# Alienware 15 r3 lines blinking on screen, is my gpu dying?

Tags: display, gpu

White horizontal lines started appearing on my alienware laptop scree , they kept increasing in frequency and now they show up even in different colors, purple and green, i Couldnt get hold of an External monitor, but i did use my phone as one and there were no lines on phone screen. Could my gpu be dying ?

Edit: alienware 15 r3, screen 120hz g-sync, gtx 1070.
Gpu performance seems unaffected (tested with furmark and valley benchmark), lines gradually increase when laptop is on even with minimal use such as watching YouTube vids, no crashes or bsod so far. Tried updating driver, and also got OEM driver, using DDU of course. Tried Everything short of a windows fresh install, and external monitor due to unavailability, i did use third party software that uses android phone as external monitor, no horizontal lines were detected on phone screen.
Edit 2 : the lines do not appear on screenshots nor do they appear on screen recording using Fraps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It could be the GPU, it could be the screen: these are the two most likely culprits. Given this is a laptop, it is difficult to replace a GPU. You can try updating your drivers, perhaps.

Comment: If you take a screenshot, are the lines visible in the screenshot?

Comment: Edited post to provide further details.

Comment: @music2myear i have not, i will try tomorrow as soon as im back home, will provide update.

Comment: @music2myear apologies for the delay, the lines do not appear on screenshots nor do they appear on screen recording using Fraps.

Comment: That indicates the issue is hardware. As this is a laptop, repair is more difficult.